# Multiple WHEN Statements in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Can I get some help on below SQL trigger. Something is wrong with using multiple "WHEN" statements.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRANS_TASKS_TRIG02
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "TASKS"
      REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(NEW.STATUS='WIP') BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PDT' );
       END IF;
    WHEN(NEW.STATUS<>'WIP') BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NULL;
       END IF;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B), you can't have multiple `when` clauses in a trigger.

You could create to separate triggers:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER TRANS_TASKS_TRIG02_WIP
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "TASKS"
      REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(NEW.STATUS='WIP') BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PDT' );
       END IF;
    END;

create or replace TRIGGER TRANS_TASKS_TRIG02_WIP
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "TASKS"
      REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(NEW.STATUS<>'WIP') BEGIN
      IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NULL;
       END IF;
    END;
```

Or have a single trigger with an `if` statement in it. Note that the `if inserting or updating` condition is redundant, since the trigger is invoked only `before insert or update`:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER TRANS_TASKS_TRIG02
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "TASKS"
  REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.STATUS='WIP' THEN
    :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NEW_TIME(SYSDATE, 'GMT', 'PDT' );
  ELSIF :NEW.STATUS<>'WIP' THEN
    :NEW.UPDATED_DATE := NULL;
  END IF;
END;
/
```